# Image files saving as broken, Pasting Icons instead of the images

Tags: mac, high-sierra, image-processing

[image]

I have been having issues with how my computer is saving images and placing images. Whenever I save an image, it views fine on my computer, but shows up as broken anywhere else when I try to upload it online, through Slack, etc... Today, I began having an issue with placing images. Usually I can copy a photo and paste it into inDesign, or other Adobe softwares, and now it's pasting the JPEG icon and not the image itself. These are very specific issues, and I have no idea what could be causing it.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting yet?

Comment: Multiple times. I also have tried uninstalling and re-installing my adobe software but the issue seems to be with the computer itself

Comment: Can you upload an example document (pdf?) somewhere that people can inspect?

Comment: It hasn't happened with pdf's, just JPEG and PNG images, and now the issue with copying images into graphic files